# Как собрать проект с targetSdkVersion 22?

Tags: android-studio

Нужно собрать проект с старыми библиотеками но я столкнулся с кучей проблем

Вот Мой build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.buratinoapps.avuploadserver"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.1'
}
```

Вот Мой settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2' // Версия Gradle плагина для сборки
    }
}
rootProject.name = "AVUploadServer"
include ':app'
```

Вот Мой gradle.propertis

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableR8=true
```

Вот Мой gradle-wrapper.propertis

```
#Mon Aug 21 11:44:19 EEST 2023
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

Лого ошибок при сборке

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\USER\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\904e2c1b11fad3a5d1b5a77ba4225f61\\transformed\\appcompat-1.0.0\\res\\values-v26\\values-v26.xml","position":{"startLine":4,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":217,"endLine":7,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":426}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\\Users\\USER\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\904e2c1b11fad3a5d1b5a77ba4225f61\\transformed\\appcompat-1.0.0\\res\\values-v26\\values-v26.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\USER\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\904e2c1b11fad3a5d1b5a77ba4225f61\\transformed\\appcompat-1.0.0\\res\\values-v26\\values-v26.xml","position":{"startLine":8,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":431,"endLine":11,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":652}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\\Users\\USER\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\904e2c1b11fad3a5d1b5a77ba4225f61\\transformed\\appcompat-1.0.0\\res\\values-v26\\values-v26.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\USER\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\904e2c1b11fad3a5d1b5a77ba4225f61\\transformed\\appcompat-1.0.0\\res\\values-v26\\values-v26.xml","position":{"startLine":12,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":657,"endLine":15,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":891}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\\Users\\USER\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\904e2c1b11fad3a5d1b5a77ba4225f61\\transformed\\appcompat-1.0.0\\res\\values-v26\\values-v26.xml:13:5-16:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\USER\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\904e2c1b11fad3a5d1b5a77ba4225f61\\transformed\\appcompat-1.0.0\\res\\values-v28\\values-v28.xml","position":{"startLine":4,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":217,"endLine":7,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":442}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\\Users\\USER\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\904e2c1b11fad3a5d1b5a77ba4225f61\\transformed\\appcompat-1.0.0\\res\\values-v28\\values-v28.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\USER\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\904e2c1b11fad3a5d1b5a77ba4225f61\\transformed\\appcompat-1.0.0\\res\\values-v28\\values-v28.xml","position":{"startLine":8,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":447,"endLine":11,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":684}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\\Users\\USER\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\904e2c1b11fad3a5d1b5a77ba4225f61\\transformed\\appcompat-1.0.0\\res\\values-v28\\values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\USER\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\378f8d1f5d9e8f2dccf5622b520d15a5\\transformed\\cardview-1.0.0\\res\\values-v23\\values-v23.xml","position":{"startLine":2,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":55,"endLine":4,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":200}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\\Users\\USER\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\378f8d1f5d9e8f2dccf5622b520d15a5\\transformed\\cardview-1.0.0\\res\\values-v23\\values-v23.xml:3:5-5:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorBackgroundFloating not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\USER\\AndroidStudioProjects\\AVUploadServer\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\themes.xml","position":{"startLine":2,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":100,"endLine":14,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":823}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\\Users\\USER\\AndroidStudioProjects\\AVUploadServer\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\themes.xml:3:5-15:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimaryVariant (aka com.buratinoapps.avuploadserver:attr/colorPrimaryVariant)' not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\USER\\AndroidStudioProjects\\AVUploadServer\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\themes.xml","position":{"startLine":2,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":100,"endLine":14,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":823}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\\Users\\USER\\AndroidStudioProjects\\AVUploadServer\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\themes.xml:3:5-15:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/colorOnPrimary (aka com.buratinoapps.avuploadserver:attr/colorOnPrimary)' not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\USER\\AndroidStudioProjects\\AVUploadServer\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\themes.xml","position":{"startLine":2,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":100,"endLine":14,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":823}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\\Users\\USER\\AndroidStudioProjects\\AVUploadServer\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\themes.xml:3:5-15:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/colorSecondaryVariant (aka com.buratinoapps.avuploadserver:attr/colorSecondaryVariant)' not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\USER\\AndroidStudioProjects\\AVUploadServer\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\themes.xml","position":{"startLine":2,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":100,"endLine":14,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":823}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\\Users\\USER\\AndroidStudioProjects\\AVUploadServer\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\themes.xml:3:5-15:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/colorOnSecondary (aka com.buratinoapps.avuploadserver:attr/colorOnSecondary)' not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\USER\\AndroidStudioProjects\\AVUploadServer\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\themes.xml","position":{"startLine":2,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":100,"endLine":14,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":823}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\\Users\\USER\\AndroidStudioProjects\\AVUploadServer\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\themes.xml:3:5-15:13: AAPT: error: resource attr/colorPrimaryVariant (aka com.buratinoapps.avuploadserver:attr/colorPrimaryVariant) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\USER\\AndroidStudioProjects\\AVUploadServer\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values-night\\themes.xml","position":{"startLine":2,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":100,"endLine":14,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":823}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\\Users\\USER\\AndroidStudioProjects\\AVUploadServer\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values-night\\themes.xml:3:5-15:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimaryVariant (aka com.buratinoapps.avuploadserver:attr/colorPrimaryVariant)' not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\USER\\AndroidStudioProjects\\AVUploadServer\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values-night\\themes.xml","position":{"startLine":2,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":100,"endLine":14,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":823}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\\Users\\USER\\AndroidStudioProjects\\AVUploadServer\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values-night\\themes.xml:3:5-15:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/colorOnPrimary (aka com.buratinoapps.avuploadserver:attr/colorOnPrimary)' not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\USER\\AndroidStudioProjects\\AVUploadServer\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values-night\\themes.xml","position":{"startLine":2,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":100,"endLine":14,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":823}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\\Users\\USER\\AndroidStudioProjects\\AVUploadServer\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values-night\\themes.xml:3:5-15:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/colorSecondaryVariant (aka com.buratinoapps.avuploadserver:attr/colorSecondaryVariant)' not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
   > 5 files found with path 'META-INF/NOTICE.md' from inputs:
      - C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\53d4fa4015bc8c33acdec7eaf5e86a12\transformed\jetified-jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar
      - C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\54d818e37843b825e51a7f0b7b988ca1\transformed\jetified-jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar
      - C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\91700edf12385d2f797f490f549d5c34\transformed\jetified-txw2-2.3.3.jar
      - C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\9d7645aa26beb43dadaea715757626a7\transformed\jetified-istack-commons-runtime-3.0.11.jar
      - C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2471111026b14fb3c5a25e47af719391\transformed\jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar
     Adding a packagingOptions block may help, please refer to
     https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
     for more information

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\904e2c1b11fad3a5d1b5a77ba4225f61\transformed\appcompat-1.0.0\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
         
     ERROR:C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\904e2c1b11fad3a5d1b5a77ba4225f61\transformed\appcompat-1.0.0\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
         
     ERROR:C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\904e2c1b11fad3a5d1b5a77ba4225f61\transformed\appcompat-1.0.0\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:13:5-16:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.
         
     ERROR:C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\904e2c1b11fad3a5d1b5a77ba4225f61\transformed\appcompat-1.0.0\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
         
     ERROR:C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\904e2c1b11fad3a5d1b5a77ba4225f61\transformed\appcompat-1.0.0\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
         
     ERROR:C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\378f8d1f5d9e8f2dccf5622b520d15a5\transformed\cardview-1.0.0\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml:3:5-5:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorBackgroundFloating not found.
         
     ERROR:C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\AVUploadServer\app\src\main\res\values\themes.xml:3:5-15:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimaryVariant (aka com.buratinoapps.avuploadserver:attr/colorPrimaryVariant)' not found.
         
     ERROR:C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\AVUploadServer\app\src\main\res\values\themes.xml:3:5-15:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/colorOnPrimary (aka com.buratinoapps.avuploadserver:attr/colorOnPrimary)' not found.
         
     ERROR:C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\AVUploadServer\app\src\main\res\values\themes.xml:3:5-15:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/colorSecondaryVariant (aka com.buratinoapps.avuploadserver:attr/colorSecondaryVariant)' not found.
         
     ERROR:C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\AVUploadServer\app\src\main\res\values\themes.xml:3:5-15:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/colorOnSecondary (aka com.buratinoapps.avuploadserver:attr/colorOnSecondary)' not found.
         
     ERROR:C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\AVUploadServer\app\src\main\res\values\themes.xml:3:5-15:13: AAPT: error: resource attr/colorPrimaryVariant (aka com.buratinoapps.avuploadserver:attr/colorPrimaryVariant) not found.
         
     ERROR:C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\AVUploadServer\app\src\main\res\values-night\themes.xml:3:5-15:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimaryVariant (aka com.buratinoapps.avuploadserver:attr/colorPrimaryVariant)' not found.
         
     ERROR:C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\AVUploadServer\app\src\main\res\values-night\themes.xml:3:5-15:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/colorOnPrimary (aka com.buratinoapps.avuploadserver:attr/colorOnPrimary)' not found.
         
     ERROR:C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\AVUploadServer\app\src\main\res\values-night\themes.xml:3:5-15:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/colorSecondaryVariant (aka com.buratinoapps.avuploadserver:attr/colorSecondaryVariant)' not found.
         

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 24s
23 actionable tasks: 23 executed
```